# How can i find filepath of a file that i downloaded with Alamofire from Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, firebase, alamofire, firebase-storage, filepath

I have some e-pubs on firebase storage.I am downloading specific e-pub with Alamofire downloadURL function but i need e-pubs filePath to open it with FolioReader.

I already tried destinationURL.path but it didn't work with FolioReader

```
downloadBookRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
        //Done
        let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = {_, _ in
            let documentsURL: NSURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as NSURL
            print("documentURL", documentsURL)
            let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("kitap\(item).epub")
            print("fileURL", fileURL ?? "")
            return (fileURL!, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
        }
        download(url!, to: destination).response { response in
            if response.error == nil, let filePath = response.destinationURL?.path {
                print("filePath", filePath)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can save that downloaded file into document directory and pass that new file url to `FolioReader `.

Comment: It already downloads in documents folder but i can't pass that path to FolioReader Is there anything wrong with my download code

Comment: Can you paste the file url which you are passing to `FolioReader `?